# Higher order expansion of hypersurface about a point (beyond second fundamental form/extrinsic curvature)

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Consider a smooth, compact $(d-1)$-dimensional hypersurface $S$ without boundary embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The surface $S$ can be described as the graph of a function $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{d-1})$. Using the tangent plane to $S$ at some point $\mathbf{x}$, endowed with an orthonormal basis $\{{\bf e}_1,\cdots,{\bf e}_{d-1}\}$, one can Taylor expand the function $f$ around ${\bf x} = 0$ as
\begin{aligned}\label{graph}
f({\bf x })  =  \frac{1}{2} K_{ij} x^{i} x^{j} + \frac{1}{3!} A_{ijk}x^{i} x^{j} x^k +  \frac{1}{4!} B_{ijkl}x^{i} x^{j} x^k x^l+ O \left(| {\bf x} |^5 \right).
\end{aligned}
The quadratic term is the extrinsic curvature of $S$ as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$, also called the second fundamental form. However, the higher order terms in the expansion are less known and I was wondering what the tensors $A$ and $B$ correspond to? I would guess they depend also on the extrinsic curvature (and its derivatives), but what is their exact form? I cannot find anything beyond second order.

Disclaimer: physicist notations

Comment: What makes you think these should be differential geometric invariants? For example, think of the pseudosphere in $\Bbb R^3$. It's given parametrically by $g(u,v)=(u-\tanh u, \text{sech }u\cos v, \text{sech }u\sin v)$ for $u>0$. It has constant curvature $-1$ but is certainly not locally a (rotated) graph of a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: P.S. It's opening a whole Pandora's box, but there is a third-order invariant, called the Pick invariant, that comes not from the Riemannian structure, but from special affine geometry. See, for example, Chapter 2 of Volume 3 of Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*. But I suspect this is taking you far, far afield.

Comment: Can you explain why a pseudosphere cannot be described locally as a graph of a quadratic polynomial? If I look in a small enough neighborhood of a point on the pseudosphere, wouldn't that be almost flat? If I look a little further, corrections wouldn't be quadratic (in some appropriate basis)?

Comment: We're not talking about approximating; we're talking about hitting the nail on the head. From the transcendental formula, you can convince yourself this can't be an algebraic surface. The proof, if you want one, is that no quadric surface other than a plane or sphere has constant curvature. You can explicitly compute the curvature of a saddle surface or hyperboloid of one sheet (the only quadric surfaces of negative curvature) and verify they are very much not constant. I guess if we look only at surfaces of revolution, we have less to check :)

Comment: Yes, I have in mind "nice" surfaces, like spheres, ellipses or smooth deformations thereof :). Without boundary I should add.

Comment: Again, a sphere has constant curvature. Although it is given as a level surface of a quadratic function, when you write it as a graph (locally), it's of course not the graph of a quadratic polynomial. So this will give you an obvious counterexample, as well.

Comment: I don't think we are talking about the same thing because the sphere can be described locally as the function $f(x)$ shown above. Take the circle of radius $R$, the function $f$ is just $f(x)= x^2/(2R) + \cdots$ at leading order around $x=0$ (choose the center of the circle at (0,R) such that the tangent plane at (0,0) is the $x$-axis).

Comment: No, the circle is not a parabola. A parabola has non-constant curvature. With the extra terms, sure, but then my point comes into play. Curvature is constant, so its derivatives are not going to help you get higher-order terms.

Comment: I cannot prolong this discussion right now. I'm about to leave for dinner.

Comment: I guess I must not have been clear enough in my question. What I am talking about is what is described here: math.stackexchange.com/q/1384905/290603. Actually, I checked your lecture notes on Differential Geometry (A First Course in
Curves and Surfaces) and what I am talking about is Exercise 2.2.21.a (p56).

Comment: Reread your own post. There's no debate about the quadratic term. You were wondering about the meaning of the coefficients of the cubic and quartic terms. This is what I've been discussing the whole time. I was arguing that they are not in a universal way determined by curvature or derivatives of curvature.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point! Now I do! If they are not in a universal way determined by curvature or derivatives of curvature, what are they constructed from (say for "nice" enough surfaces)?

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by summarizing what you're doing: Fix a point $p$ on the hypersurface $S$. Move the hypersurface rigidly so that the point is at the origin and the hypersurface is the graph of a function $f$ that has a critical point at the origin. Then the $k$-th order term of the Taylor series of $f$ at the origin defines a symmetric $k$-tensor on $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$. If you do this for each point in the hypersurface, you get a symmetric $k$-tensor field along the entire hypersurface.

We can calculate the second and third order tensors at the origin as follows: $\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$

Consider a function $f: O \rightarrow \R$, where $O\subset \R^{d-1}$ is open. Assume $$f(0) = \partial_1f(0) = \dots = \partial_{d-1}f(0) = 0.$$ Let $\phi: O \rightarrow \R^d$ be the graph map
$$
  \phi(x^1, \dots, x^{d-1}) = (x^1, \dots, x^{d-1},f(x^1, \dots, x^{d-1})).
$$
Let $\nu: O \rightarrow S^{d-1} \subset \R^d$ be the Gauss map composed with $\phi$. Observe that for $k \ge 2$, the $k$-order tensor $A$ at $0$ is given by
$$
  A_{i_1\dots i_k}(0) = \nu(0)\cdot \partial^k_{i_1\cdots i_k}\phi(0).
$$
On the other hand, if $k=2$,
\begin{align*}
  \nu\cdot\partial^2_{ij}\phi &= \partial_j(\nu\cdot\partial_i\phi) - \partial_j\nu\cdot\partial_i\phi\\
                              &= -\partial_i\phi\cdot S(\partial_j\phi)\\
                              &= -K_{ij},
\end{align*}
where $S$ is the shape operator and $K$ is the second fundamental form. Evaluating this at $0$, we get $A_{ij} = -K_{ij}$.

Next,
\begin{align*}
  \nu\cdot\partial^3_{ijk}\phi &= \partial_k(\nu\cdot\partial^2_{ij}\phi) - \partial_k\nu\cdot\partial^2_{ij}\phi\\
                               &= -\partial_kK_{ij} - S(\partial_k\phi)\cdot\partial^2_{ij}\phi.
\end{align*}
Evaluating this at $0$,
\begin{align*}
  A_{ijk} &=   \nu\cdot\partial^3_{ijk}\phi\\
  &= -\partial_kK_{ij}\\
  &= -\nabla_kK_{ij}.
\end{align*}
Observe that a consequence of this is the Codazzi-Mainardi equations.

I do not know what happens for $k=4$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining a bit more the steps between equalities for both k=2 and 3 ? Also, do you have any references (books, lecture notes, etc.) that discuss this? I'll try working out the k=4 order.

Comment: For the order $k=4$, based on dimensionality, my guess would be that $A_{ijkl}=a\nabla_i\nabla_j K_{kl} + b K K_{ij}K_{kl} + c K_{in}K^n_{\;j}K_{kl}$.

Comment: Sorry but I'm leaving the details as well as what happens for $k=4$ as exercises for the reader. The basic idea is to keep track of which vectors are tangent and which are normal to the hypersurface.

Comment: I did an initial calculation for $k=4$ and it appears to involve first order partial derivatives of the Christoffel symbols associated with the map $\phi$. This is not surprising. Using these graph coordinates, the Christoffel symbols with respect to what one could call tangent graph coordinates at each point vanish at their point but their partial derivatives need not do so. Moreover, these derivatives of Christoffel symbols are nontrivial invariants of the embedding. And despite appearances, they do define tensors.

Comment: I tried doing the calculation for $k=2$ as in your answer, I got there: $\nu\partial^4_{ijkl} \phi = \partial_l(\nu \partial^3_{ijk}\phi) - (\partial_l\nu)\partial^3_{ijk}\phi=-\nabla_l\nabla_kK_{ij} -\partial_l(S(\partial_k\phi)\partial^2_{ij}\phi)- (\partial_l\nu)\partial^3_{ijk}\phi$.. But then I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You mean $k=4$, right? It’s definitely much less clear on how to proceed and the end result is unsatisfying. I suggest that, unless you have a good reason to pursue this, you might want to pursue something different.

Comment: I meant $k=4$, indeed! I agree, it seems very cumbersome.. I thought my guess based on dimensionality could be a partial answer but it's probably not as simple as you said.. Though if you can post a partial result, that would be nice.